# Accessing localhost (xampp) from another computer over LAN network - how to?

Tags: apache-2.2, localhost, xampp, httpd.conf

I have just set up a wi-fi network at home. I have all my files on my desktop computer (192.168.1.56) and want to access localhost over there from another computer (192.168.1.2).

On my desktop I can access localhost through the normal http://localhost. Apache is running on port 80 as usual.

Exactly what do I have to do to achieve this? There is documentation on the net but they either don't work or are too fragment and confusing to understand.

I think I have to make changes to my apache's httpd.conf file and the hosts file. Any ideas as to what changes to make?

Answer (score 4):

[**localhost**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) is the name given to the IP loopback address 127.0.0.1. Every computer in a network has a localhost address that points to itself. To access your files on your main computer you can use `http://192.168.1.56`. You could also edit the [hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) file on the client(s) and assign a name to 192.168.1.56 edit `/etc/hosts` (unixlike systems) or `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` for windows systems e.g.

```
192.168.1.56    homeserver.lan
```

then you will be able to access the server as `http://homeserver.lan`

Edit: From the comments below, the port was being blocked by a firewall.

Comment: but I am not able to access http://192.168.1.56 (the IP address is dynamic, does that make a difference?) or http://desktoppcname... i really doubt that making changes to the hosts file will make any difference...

Comment: @vr3690: Check that your desktop pc will allow connections through it's firewall on port 80 (http).

Comment: bingo. when i use http://192.168.1.56 on desktop pc, i am able to see the site. so I am guessing I have a firewall problem. how do I fix this?

Comment: @vr3690: You don't provide any information about the OS on your desktop PC. If it is windows have a look [here](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles/Customizing-Windows-Firewall.html)

Comment: yes. got it working. allowed port 80 limiting the scope to my subnet. thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Out of the box Apache's default vhost configs might offer something if you try this in your browser: `http://192.168.1.56'.

If that works look in the `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` file (this may differ slightly on your OS) and change `DocumentRoot` to point to where the files you want to access are.

This isn't exactly secure if both machines are connected to the Internet but if you're not Port Forwarding on a NAT router to port 80 out to the Internet for serving Web pages then it's not the end of the world.

Remember to `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart` or similar after changes.

(It's probably worth saying at this point that using HTTP to share files across a LAN probably it's the obvious and ideal solution but the myriad of other solutions available are outwith this question most likely).